# Dilation equation of motion (2D Dilation gravity)

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, curvature

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9501071.pdf) "Les Houches Lectures on Black Holes",  we have the action given as: (Eqn 3.6),
$$ S = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g} e^{-2 \phi } [R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2] $$

This is a 1 + 1-dimensional theory of gravity coupled to
a dilaton field $\phi$. The equation of motion for dilation field $\phi$ is obtained as Equation 3.8:
$$ R - 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2 + 4\Box \phi = 0 $$

But, when I try to rederive the equation of motion for the dilation field $\phi$, I am getting a different sign.

$$ S = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g} e^{-2 \phi } [R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2] $$
$$ \delta S = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g} \delta (e^{-2 \phi }) [R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2] + 
 e^{-2 \phi } \delta[R + 4g^{uv}\nabla_u \phi \nabla_v \phi + 4 \lambda^2]$$
$$ = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g}(-2e^{-2 \phi }) [R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2]\delta\phi + 
 e^{-2 \phi } (4*2 g^{uv}\nabla_u \delta\phi \nabla_v \phi)$$
$$ = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g}(-2e^{-2 \phi }) [R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2]\delta\phi -
 e^{-2 \phi } (8g^{uv}\nabla_u  \nabla_v \phi\delta\phi) + \text{bdr. terms}$$

Dilation Equation of motion is then:
$$ R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2 + 4g^{uv}\nabla_u  \nabla_v \phi = 0 $$
$$ R + 4(\nabla \phi)^2 + 4 \lambda^2 + 4\Box \phi = 0 $$

As you can see the sign in $ 4(\nabla \phi)^2$ is different than obtained in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the boundary term!!! The term as a whole is: $e^{-2\phi}4\nabla^{a}δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi$. It seems that you ignored the $e^{-2\phi}$. The correct calculation for the boundary term is:

$$\nabla^{a}(e^{-2\phi}4δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi) = \nabla^{a}(e^{-2\phi})4δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi + e^{-2\phi}4\nabla^{a}δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi + e^{-2\phi}4δ\phi \nabla^{a}\nabla_{a}\phi$$

Τhe left hand side term is zero. The second term in the right hand side is what you have, so solving for it:

$$+ e^{-2\phi}4\nabla^{a}δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi = -\nabla^{a}(e^{-2\phi})4δ\phi \nabla_{a}\phi - e^{-2\phi}4δ\phi \nabla^{a}\nabla_{a}\phi $$

Now you have to take the derivative of the exponential and you will obtain the desired result.